# Which are the measurable sets with respect to this construction of an outer dirac-type measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $x \in \Omega$ and $\mathcal{A} \subset\mathcal{P}(X)$ an at most countable set with $\emptyset, \Omega \in \mathcal{A}$. Let

$$ \delta_x: \mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty], 
\quad A \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
1 &\text{if } x\in A\\
0 &\text{else}.
\end{cases}$$

Now consider the extension of $\delta_x$ to the outer measure $\overline\delta_x$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by the [Caratheodory construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Construction_of_outer_measures). Which are the sets of measure zero with respect to $\overline\delta_x$ and of which sets does the $\sigma$-algebra of $\overline\delta_x$-measurable sets $\Sigma(\overline\delta_x)$ consist?

The problem here is the generality of $\mathcal{A}$, since for a set $N \in X$ with $x \not\in N$ we don't know a priori that there will be a countable covering $(B_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $N$ with $B_k \in \mathcal{A}$ and $x \not\in B_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. But if such a covering exists, $N$ is a set of measure zero.

**What about the other $\overline\delta_x$-measurable sets? How would I characterize them?** I think I should use the Definition of $\overline\delta_x$-measureability as

> A set $A \subset X$ is $\overline\delta_x$-measureable iff for all $T \subset X$
>   $$
>  \overline\delta_x(A \cap T) + \overline\delta_x(A^C \cap T) \leq \overline\delta_x(T).
> $$

**I have the suspicion that $\Sigma(\overline\delta_x)$ only consists of the sets of measure zero and their complements, but I'm not sure how to prove this.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you have answered what sets are of measure $0$. They are exactely subsets of union of all $B \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x \not \in B$. Asume that there is mesurable set $A$, than:
$$(1) \: \: \: \:\delta_x(A)+\delta_x(A^c)=1$$ and what is more measure of every set is $0$ or $1$ so if $A$ wasn't of measure $0$ it was of measure $1$ and thanks to $(1)$ its complement is of measure $0$ so only mesurable sets are of measure $0$ or are their complements (as you suspected).

Comment: Ok, but are there measurable sets other than the sets of measure 0?

Comment: i mean ofcourse yes because the whole space has measure 1.